# I cannot understand the difference of the Rust code

Tags: algorithm, rust

I'm trying to solve this problem in codewars.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/are-they-the-same/

I wrote the following code.

```rust
fn comp(mut a: Vec<i64>, mut b: Vec<i64>) -> bool {
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    a = a.iter().map(|x| x * x).collect();

    a == b
}
```

The judge system says there is an input that my code returns false but should be true. I cannot understand what is the problem.

I saw answers of other people who passed all tests. This is the one of them.

```
fn comp(a: Vec<i64>, b: Vec<i64>) -> bool {
    let mut a1 = a.iter().map(|&x| x * x).collect::<Vec<_>>(); 
    let mut a2 = b;
    a1.sort();
    a2.sort();
    a1 == a2
}
```

The order of squaring and sorting is important?

Comment: `-2 < -1` but `(-2)² > (-1)²`, so the order is important.

Comment: Thank you!!! Could you write it in answer? I'll choose your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely some inputs contain negative numbers, for which the order does matter. Eg. `-2 < -1`, but `(-2)² > (-1)²`.